# Searching and updating based on custom field - Jira Python

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-java-api

I have a custom field named "**Detailed Status**"  of the type *Text Field (< 255 characters)* with custom field ID value of 10000.

I am writing a JIRA Python script to update the value of this custom field of a number of issues having a particular value for this field.

Lets say I want to update all the issues having the custom field value as "*Test Value*" with another value called, say, "*New Value*".

I am just getting started on JIRA Python scripting, so based on what I read on [documentation](http://jira-python.readthedocs.org), this is how my code looks like as of now.

```
from jira.client import JIRA
jira_options={'server': 'http://localhost:8080'}
jira=JIRA(options=jira_options,basic_auth=('usrname','pwd'))
for issue in jira.search_issues(' cf[10000] = "Test Value" ', maxResults=3):
    issue.update(fields={'Detailed Status': 'New Value'})
```

I am however, getting the following error.

```
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    for issue in jira.search_issues(' cf[10000] = "Test Value" ', maxResults=3):

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jira\client.py", line 1000, in search_issues
    resource = self._get_json('search', search_params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jira\client.py", line 1396, in _get_json
    raise_on_error(r)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jira\exceptions.py", line 36, in raise_on_
error
    raise JIRAError(r.status_code, error, r.url)
jira.exceptions.JIRAError: HTTP 400: "Field 'cf[10000]' is not searchable, it is
 only sortable."
http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/search?jql=+cf%5B10000%5D+%3D+%22Test+Value%22+
&startAt=0&maxResults=3
```

I also tried with `cf[10000] ~ 'Test Value'` but it gave the same error as above.

Could you please tell me what I might be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you defined the custom field, did you enable a Searcher for it? That's likely the problem, based on the error message

Comment: This was indeed the solution. Thank you @mdoar !

Answer (score 0):

Just adding the code that worked for me, after I enabled a Searcher for the custom field, as per the answer given by @mdoar above.

```
from jira.client import JIRA
jira_options={'server': 'http://localhost:8080'}
jira=JIRA(options=jira_options,basic_auth=('usrname','pwd'))

for issue in jira.search_issues(' cf[10000] ~ "Test Value" '):
    issue.update(fields={'customfield_10000': 'New value'})
```